# вопрос по межсетевым экранам

Tags: экран

NAT И VPN ЭТО МЕЖСЕТЕВЫЕ ЭКРАНЫ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет.

NAT - это "Network Address Translation". Эта технология работает так:

вот сидите вы дома. Перед вами ноутбук, рядом лежит сотовый телефон, а в углу стоит умный телевизор (он наказан, за то, что слишком умный). И все эти устройства выходят в интернет через роутер, в который со стороны прровайдера входит один провод. И этот роутер выглядит для провайдера как одно устройство.

Вот внутри роутера работает NAT. Когда компьютер хочет зайти на VK.COM, он отправляет запрос по HTTP. Этот запрос преобразуется в последовательность ТСР пакетов. У них есть "адрес отправителя (это Ваш ноутбук, пусть он имеет IP = 192.168.1.100) и адрес получателя = 93.186.225.208.

И вот пакеты начинают по кабелю покидать Вашу квартиру. Приходят на сервера "вконтактика", и он начинает отвечать. Но, как Вы понимаете, если "вконтактик" отправит пакет на адрес 192.168.1.100, то этот пакет никуда не придёт. Потому что диапазон адресов 192.168.x.x предназанчен для использования "только внутри квартиры", то есть, в локальной сети.

Как же пакеты попадают обратно в Вашу кваритру? Об этом заботится роутер. Он знает, что он выходит в интернет с адреса, предположим, 89.188.240.150. И у кажого пакета, который выходит за порог Вашей квартиры, роутер исправляет адрес отправителя с 192.168.1.100 на 89.188.240.150. И запоминает этот факт в своих внутреннних таблицах. А когда приходит ответ - то он исправляет адрес получателя с 89.188.240.150 на 192.168.1.100 и пропускает пакет в квартиру, где пакет находит Ваш ноутбук и благополучно путешествует по его сетевому стеку обратно в браузер.

Итак, это был NAT.

VPN - это "Virtual Private Network". Это способ распространить понятие локальной сети на компьютеры, находящиеся в разных местах и не связанные физической сетью друг с другом.

Грубо говоря, вы решаете с Вашим другом, который живёт в другом городе, поиграть в какую нибудь старую игру. Выпущенную в то время, когда игры вообще ничего не знали про интернет, интернета не было, а были только локальные сети.

Тогда Вы "поднимаете" VPN - соединение с Вашим другом, и ваши компьютеры оказываются "виртуально рядом". Грубо говоря, Ваш компьютер по прежнему имеет адрес  192.168.1.100, а компьютер друга получает адрес 192.168.1.101. Они перкрасно видят друг друга в рамках локальной сети, и Вы можете играть.

А можете работать, например, находясь дома, но благодаря VPN видя рабочие файловые сервера, принтеры и прочие сетевые устройства.

Итак, это был VPN

А то, что называается "сетвой экран" (он же firewall) - это что то вроде привратника. Он стоит на "входе" (то есть, пропускает через себя весь сетевой трафик) и у кажого входящего пакета спрашивает "ты кто? ты к кому?". Ну, на самом то деле у него просто есть таблица, в которой написаны правила: пакеты, пришедшие на порт 8080, к примеру, пропускать, на порт 139 - пропускать, а все остальные - игнорировать. Правила могут быть и более сложными: "пакетам, пришедшим из сети blizzard - путь открыт! А вот насчет остальных - это мы еще посмотрим"

Понятно объяснил?

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: А коммутатор и vlan являются межсетевым экраном?

Comment: Вы можете отметить вопрос как "решающий вашу проблему", поставив "зеленую галочку" рядом с моим ответом. Если, конечно, он действительно решает Вашу проблему. При этом рейтинг на этом сайте увеличивается не только у меня, но и у Вас :-)

Comment: "коммутатор" - это очень широкое понятие. Обычно "коммутатором" называют "хаб" или "свитч" - устройства, предназначенные для коммутации пакетов. Они не являются экранами, они предназначены только для передачи данных. Не фильтруя их. vlan - это "virual LAN" - технология, предназанченная для создания на базе одной физической сети нескольких разделенных между собой логических локальных сетей. я бы сказал, что тоже - "нет"

Comment: у меня тут тест: коммутатор, прокси сервер, vlan, nat: из этих 2 должен быть межсетевой экран

Comment: ну, тест туповат, но это ворос к составителям теста. я бы ответил "прокси сервер" и "nat". Эти - хоть что то фильтруют.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо