# Почему не работает сервер?

Tags: c#, json, сервер, tcp

Имею TCP сервер, который работает на порте 11000 ( по-идее должен работать ).
На моменте server.Start() происходит ошибка System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: "Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен"

Открывал порт, но ничего не помогло. ( П.С Возможно, если это поможет, то делал открытие портов по этому видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hO6V48GvmSI ( 3 минута видео )

```
 WebClient webclient = new WebClient();

            string ip = webclient.DownloadString("https://api.ipify.org/");

            int port = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            Console.WriteLine(localEndPoint.Address + ":" + localEndPoint.Port);

            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(localEndPoint);


            try
            {
                server.Start();
            }
            catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Пожалуйста, откройте соответствующий порт, после чего заново запустите сервер. Нажмите любую кнопку для выхода.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                throw new Exception("Порты закрыты.");
            }
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял Ваш код, Вы спрашиваете IP у внешнего сервера. Чему у вас равна переменная ip? По моему, он даёт Вам адрес Ваего компа в интернете. Но локальный ip - это ip вида 192.168.1.100, например. Именно к нему и надо биндиться. А еще лучше - биндиться к 0.0.0.0, что означает "любой сетевой интерфейс". Ну, или я сего то не понял :-) Если я прав - посмотрите еще мой ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1261377/вопрос-по-межсетевым-экранам/

Comment: @S.H. Спасибо большое за ответ. Да, я спрашиваю IP у внешнего сервера ( получаю внешний IP ). 
Можете сказать, при бинде на локальный IP ко мне сможет подключиться мой товарищ? ( к моему серверу )

Comment: > при бинде на локальный IP ко мне сможет подключиться мой товарищ? - именно для этого Вы открываете порт на роутере. Пакеты приходят на роутер, он их роутит на локальный комп. Прямо как в том ответе, который я советовал прочитать

Comment: @S.H У меня идет напрямую подключение к ПК ( у меня нету роутера - кабель подключен напрямую ). Это как-то меняет ситуацию?

Comment: По моему, то, что кабель подключен напрямую - не меняет ситуацию. Но надо попробовать :-)

Comment: @S.H Спасибо большое за ответ : )

Comment: Не за что. Поясню: даже в случае прямого подключения кабеля внутри компа всё равно осуществляется роутинг. Например, это можно увидеть, введя команду route print. Вы, попробовав, напишите еще раз, если будут проблемы - будем еще советовать :-)

Comment: @S.H Извините, что еще раз пишу, но возникла проблема: при попытке подключения к моему другу выдает такую ошибку: https://imgur.com/aWiLBC7 
Это его локальный IP. Порты открыты.

Comment: Мне кажется, подключаться нужно, как раз используя публичный IP. То сеть, при биндинге в программе Вы биндите её к любому интерфейсу, в том числе - к локальному, но при подключении - используете публичный IP адрес

Comment: @S.H Сейчас прибиндились к 0.0.0.0, пытаюсь подключиться по публичному IP - не робит.

Comment: Хм, через час-два попробю проверить у себя!

Comment: @S.H Если что, я брал публичный адрес отсюда https://api.ipify.org/

Comment: @S.H Простите за неудобства, но можете не морочить себе голову. Проблема была на стороне друга.

Comment: Эх, а я уже развернулся и начал писать приложеньку для тестирования! Заработало? все стало более-менее на свои места?

Comment: @S.H Извините, что так вышло. Буквально вот-вот с другом попробывали на моём ПК. Проблема была на его стороне тогда.

Comment: Сервер, имею в виду, попробывали на моём ПК

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем то, я написал свои соображения в комментарии к вопросу, но решил оформить всё как ответ.

Если я правильно понял Ваш код, Вы спрашиваете IP у внешнего сервера. Чему у вас равна переменная ip? По моему, он даёт Вам адрес Вашего компа в интернете, то есть публичный IP. Как правило, этот IP принадлежит роутеру, через котрый происходит "выход в интернет", и к нему нельзя биндиться.

А bind нужно делать к локальному IP - это ip вида 192.168.1.100, например.

Вот такая "кривенькая и косенькая" процедура должна Вам помочь в случае опеределния IP в локальной сети: (правда, если у компа несколько IP, например, на разных интерфейсах - она вернет их все. Тогд - надо взять один из них)

```cs
using System.Net;
```

```cs
public string HostIp()
{
    string compIP = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        string myHost = Dns.GetHostName();
        // !!! Здесь есть неточность, реально адреса интранет 172.16.x.x - 172.32.x.x
        foreach (IPAddress ip in Dns.GetHostEntry(myHost).AddressList)
        {
            string ipString = ip.ToString();
            if (ipString.StartsWith("192.168.") || ipString.StartsWith("10.") || ipString.StartsWith("172.16"))
                compIP += string.IsNullOrEmpty(compIP) ? ipString : "; " + ip;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
    return compIP;
}
```

Попробуйте использовать опрделяемый таким образом адрес - ошибка должна исчезнуть. А порт Вы, скорее всего, открыли правильно.

PS. В комментариях накопилось много дополнительной информации и справедливойй критики, я постараюсь переписать ответ, учтя все эти замечания

Comment: `.IndexOf("...") == 0` можно заменить на `.StartsWith("...")`. тоже и с `.EndsWith("...")`. или тут опять какие-то приколы со строками и культурой или чем-то таким

Comment: да и `ip.ToString()` можно в отдельную переменную вынести

Comment: @return - с критикой согласен, поэтому я и написал про код что он "кривенький" - при случае улучшу его по Вашему совету

Comment: Немного подправил код не меняя логики, но вообще код этого метода можно свести к `public static string HostIp() => string.Join("; ", Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.Where(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork && !IPAddress.IsLoopback(ip)));` При этом проверка айпишника на принадлежность к сетям не имеет смысла примерно никакого. Главное - не зацепить 127.x.x.x. С другой стороны, если надо проверять подсеть, то есть [более прикольные и легко гуглящиеся методы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56461160/12888024).

Comment: Если же надо биндиться на конкретный сетевой интерфейс, то IP надо именно с него брать, а не с хостнейма, то есть подход в корне другой по идее должен быть.

Comment: @aepot - Вы наш герой! я с восторгом читаю не только Ваши ответы, но меня восхищает, что кто то в сууботу утром исправляет мой неудачный код. А насчет хоста - да, но там выше в вопросе в комментариях автор вопроса уже разобрался. Для меня это был повод освежить свои зания, возможно, я перепишу ответ.

Comment: Самое неудачное в этом коде - это проглатывание исключений не имея на то оснований. :) Остальное нормально.

Comment: я как пионЭр - обещаю исправить.. просто когда неделя начнётся, будет немного больше на это времени

Comment: Еще странность, вы пишете `адреса интернет`, быть может вы имели в виду "интранет", то есть внутреннюю сеть?

Comment: @aepot - эту часть ответа я переписал прямо сейчас, там имелось в виду, что автор вопроса пытается биндиться к публичному IP, который не его компе может быть просто не доступен.