# Как создать соединение через интернет, а не через имитатор локальной сети?

Tags: python-3.x, сокет, p2p

Имеется программа, создающая p2p-чат. Программа превосходно работает на одном пк, позволяя чатиться с самим собой. Но при попытке подключения к другому пк вызывается следующее исключение:

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера

Решить проблему помогает имитатор локальной сети Radmin VPN, если подключаться по ip, предоставляемым этим приложением, но я хочу избавиться от этой обязательной зависимости.

Код:

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
import time

port = 9091

data = None


def server():
    global data
    global port
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), port))
    print("Server started your ip", socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
    sock.listen(1)
    conn, addr = sock.accept()

    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if data.decode('utf-8') == 'stop':
            print(f'Anybody>>> {data.decode("utf-8")}')
            sock.close()
            return None
        else:
            print(f'Anybody>>> {data.decode("utf-8")}')
        conn.send(f'Server {data.decode("utf-8")}'.encode("utf-8"))


def client():
    global data
    time.sleep(0.1)
    sock = socket.socket()
    while True:  # Получение ip для подключения
        ip = input('ip to connect>>> ')
        try:
            sock.connect((ip, port))
            break
        except:
            print('invalid ip or connect error')

    while True:  # Процесс отправки сообщений
        message = input('You>>> ')
        if message == 'stop':
            sock.send(message.encode("utf-8"))
            sock.close()
            return None
        else:
            sock.send(message.encode("utf-8"))
        data = sock.recv(1024)


p1 = threading.Thread(target=server, name="t1")
p2 = threading.Thread(target=client, name="t2")

p1.start()
p2.start()
```

Заранее благодарен

Comment: "Но при попытке подключения к другому пк"... - а можете уточнить, как именно Вы вводите в программу адрес другого ПК?

Comment: Когда программа запускается на другом ПК, там выводится надпись в консоли "Server started your ip <ip данного ПК>". По этому адресу я и подключаюсь уже на своём ПК, когда программа требует ввода ip для подключения, выводя "ip to connect>>> "

Comment: А можно пример такого адреса привести? я не для того, чтобы "взломать по IP", а потому, что мне кажется - Вы путаете адреса в локальной сети и адреса интернета. Можете почитать такую "объяснялку": https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1261377/

Comment: 10x[Nat](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT)