# Можно ли подключиться к внешнему IP с помощью tcp?

Tags: c#, tcp

С помощью этих строк кода я получаю ip устройства и создаю TcpListener и TcpClient

```
string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
IPAddress[] ipAdresses = ipEntry.AddressList;

listener = new TcpListener(ipAdresses[1], port);
```

Подключение хорошо работает, но только если и клиент и сервер находятся в одной сети (WiFi или мобильная точка доступа).
Можно ли как-то выйти в "глобальную сеть"? То есть, чтобы я мог подключиться к серверу с другого ip адреса?
При этом есть такое условие, что сервер можно развернуть на любом устройстве (Потому что я находил информацию про настройки портов и маршрутизатора, но мне это не подойдёт, так как пользователь сам разворачивает сервер)

Получается такая схема: любой пользователь может создать сервер на своём устройстве и любой другой пользователь, зная порт и ip может к этому серверу подключиться.

Comment: Далеко не любое устройство имеет внешний IP-адрес (это зависит не от устройства, а от интернет-провайдера), поэтому в формулировке «на любом устройстве» — нет, нельзя

Comment: @andreymal хм, а если не на любом, то какие действия в теории необходимо сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уважаемый Art, я перескажу Вам некоторое кол-во известных вещей, за что заранее извиняюсь.

Ваш вопрос в формулировке "на любом устройстве можно запустить клиент и/или сервер, и любое устройство может соединиться с любым" - могло бы работать, если бы речь шла об IPv6. Это стандарт, в котором количество адресов настолько велико, что можно выдать IP адрес каждому устройству.

Но обычно речь идёт об обыкновенном IPv4, то есть, о привычных нам адресах вида 110.72.28.75, или что то в таком духе.

Как Вы можете сами подсчитать, кол-во различных адресов в такой схеме адресации - это немного меньше, чем два в тридцать второй степени, или, другими словами, около 4 миллиардов адресов.

Вообще говоря, в сети сейчас уже больше четырех миллиардов устройств. В то же время, все публичные IP-адреса в сети Интернет уникальны и не могут повторяться.

Возможно такое парадоксальное несоответствие благодаря тому, что есть локальные сети.

В локальной сети множество устройств может выходить "наружу, в большой интернет" через один и тот же IP-адрес. Для этого используется NAT - Network Address Translation. О том, как это происходит, я писал [в таком вот ответе на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1261377/)

Еще одно замечание насчет терминологии: у нас адреса устройств могут быть "белыми" ("честные" интернет - адреса, такие же, как у какого то крупного сайта) и "серыми" - это именно те IP адреса, которые используются внутри локальных сетей. К ним относятся:

От 10.0.0.0 до 10.255.255.255 с маской 255.0.0.0 или /8

От 172.16.0.0 до 172.31.255.255 с маской 255.240.0.0 или /12

От 192.168.0.0 до 192.168.255.255 с маской 255.255.0.0 или /16 (этот диапазон используется в домашних сетях чаще всего)

От 100.64.0.0 до 100.127.255.255 с маской подсети 255.192.0.0 или /10

Итак, адреса из "серых" диапазонов - не "торчат" напрямую в интернет, а выходят в интернет через маршрутизатор. Иногда - даже через несколько маршрутизаторов, но сейчас это не важно.

Теперь вернёмся к Вашему вопросу.

Вот у нас есть клиент и сервер. Возможны следуюие варианты:

1. Хороший вариант - и клиент, и сервер имеют "белые" адреса. Могут устанавливать соединения как угодно.
2. у сервера - "белый" IP, у клиента - "серый". Часто встречается в жизни, но клиенту это не мешает установить соединение с сервером.
3. Наоборт: у сервера - "серый" IP, у клиента - "белый" IP. ТОгда можно пойти на хитрость: придумать протокол, по которому сервер будет активно устанавливать соединение с клиентом. То есть, мы "переворачиваем"
   схему из пункта 2). И опять - всё работает!
4. Наконец, самый плохой вариант: и клиент,  и сервер имеют "серые" IP. В этом случае обмен информацией между ними невозможен... напрямую. То есть, обычным способом, которым мы действовали в пунктах 1), 2) и 3). Но - есть обходные пути. Например, обмен инфорацией через специальный сервер, которы предназначен только для того, чтобы гонять через него трафик таких вот "невезучих". В частности, в качестве такого сервера может выступать одна из "более везучих" нод, имеющих "белый" IP. Так когда то работал Skype (еще на заре своего развития, до того, как его купил Microsoft). Также, есть много способов и и комбинаций, объединенённых под общим названием "прокалывание firewall" - [Firewall Piercing](http://xgu.ru/wiki/Firewall_Piercing). Погуглите, там встречаются удивительно оригинальные подходы.

Наконец, есть целый "раздел" децентрализованных сетей. Вот там способность установить соединение с кем угодно и когда угодно возведено в ранг искусства. Можно начать с [matrix](https://matrix.org/), и углубляться в эту тему, пока хватит терпения.

Я надеюсь, мои объяснения хотя бы отчасти помогут Вам разобраться в этом увлекательном вопросе. Пишите в комментариях, если нужно еще что то уточнить!

Comment: Port Forwarding? DMZ? Маршрутизаторы? IPv6 не поддерживает полинтернета на сегодняшний день, поэтому данную технологию можно вообще выкинуть из обсуждения как далекую туманную перспективу.

Comment: @aepot - я правильно Вас понял, что эти штуки - порт форвардинг и т.п. - нужно включить в ответ? Просто автор вопроса пишет "Потому что я находил информацию про настройки портов и маршрутизатора, но мне это не подойдёт, так как пользователь сам разворачивает сервер". Но Вы правы - для полноты картины, наверное, лучше включить!

Comment: Port Forwarding требует 2 вещи: поддержку роутером и фиксированный IP и порт сервера в локалке. Это самый популярный способ открыться во внешку при условии наличия белого IP на роутере. И здесь же стоит упомянуть, что практически все провайдеры предоставляют статический белый IP как платную услугу за сравнительно небольшие деньги. Многие об этом даже не знают.

Comment: @aepot - да, справедливо, для хорошего ответа нужно это добавить, причем с картиночкой.... скоро займусь, что делать! :-)

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное за такой развернутый ответ! Я только начинаю изучать сетевые взаимодействия и своим ответом вы сильно помогли мне.

Comment: @S.H. подскажите, я правильно понимаю, что если сервер поддерживает IPv6, то с клиента я смогу беспрепятственно подключиться по этому адресу?

Comment: @Art - к сожаению, нет. Из за того, что, как написано выше в комментариях, "IPv6 не поддерживает полинтернета на сегодняшний день" - это лишь возможно в туманном будущем. Когда ВСЁ оборудование в цепочке от сервера до любого клиента поддерживает IPv6.
Гораздо более реалистичной выглядит перспектива настройки сервера так, чтобы его можно было видеть по IPv4, несмотря на нахождение в "серых" адресах.